# Can you run google maps api in android studio without internet

Tags: android, google-maps

I have watched tutorials on how to integrate google maps in an android application. Before I put google maps in my android application, I want to know if you need internet connection to run the application that runs google maps?

--------------------Answer to question above has been solved---------------------

I have another question. What are the things that an offline map can do? Can the offline map do pathfinding? Can you get coordinates, distances and other map data from it? Or is it just a map that can only be viewed?

Comment: Uh. Run the application without an internet connection and see what happens.. ;-)

Comment: can you read my updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have watched tutorials about that you might have noted that the maps api needs permission.INTERNET which is also obvious as the maps need to be loaded from Google. How else should they come to your device or simulator?

Comment: oh thats why there was a link to google maps. Can you see my updated post? I have another question.

Comment: you should read the documentation. if your question was answered, you should mark it as answered and open a new question (after reading the documentation). Obviously because of the low quality of your initial question I got a downvote for my answer.

Comment: @Christian I don't think that could be a valid reason for a downvote but who knows if someone actually did just because of the question.